# push and endpush to Stack laravel problem

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

See if you can find an alternative to this. I have a @stack('header_scripts') and I want to render from there multiple scripts like `<scripts></scripts>` in my website.

For example, this is my **master_page.blade.php**:

```
<head>
    @stack('header_scripts)
</head>
```

And this is my index.blade.php:

```
<div class="promotion">
    -45% DISCOUNT!
    @push('header_scripts')
        <script>
            //show promotion and send data to Google Anlytics from here
        </script>
    @endpush
</div>

<div class="container>
    //some products list here
    @push('header_scripts')
        <script>
            //show all the products and send data to Google Anlytics
        </script>
    @endpush
</div>
```

Etc, etc.

The problem is that the last push to the stack overwrites the first push code.

How can I do this?

Comment: that shouldnt happen, could be a bug in laravel 5.2? If you really cant do `@push` twice in the same view then perhaps you'd have to rewrite to a single one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
        @stack('css')
    </head>
    <body>
        @stack('js')
    </body>



@extends('layouts.admin.app')

@section('title','Tag')

@push('css')
    <link href="{{ asset('admin/plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush

@section('content')

@endsection

@push('js')
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/jquery-datatable/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

Comment: simple use push and end push